# Table design for 1:N relations with ordering and filtering on both sides of the relation in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, index-tuning

we have some tables with a lot of records (millions) and try to keep everything up to speed, but on the other hand we are setting our application up in new countries and keep some data per country. At first we made columns per country, but as the number of countries grow and having a limit of 64 indexes per table (and a limit on row-length) we cannot proceed this way.

We thought of having a `foo_countries` table with a `country` column. But we now filter and sort in both tables in 1 query. This doesn't seem like the right way either. I've been reading a lot across the internet and some people say to include the actual data of the parent table into the related table, (optionally with triggers) but this seems overly complex and very prone to inconsistencies between different countries.

We also thought to have a `country` column on the table `foo` itself, but having this duplicates all records per country and doesn't help in the relations to this table (there are FK's referencing `foo`).

Current table structure (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_count_fr` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
  `product_count_de` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `foo_slug_brand_id_unique` (`slug`,`brand_id`),
  KEY `foo_brand_product_count_fr_idx` (`brand_id`,`product_count_fr`),
  KEY `foo_brand_product_count_de_idx` (`brand_id`,`product_count_de`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `view_count_fr` != 0 AND `brand_id` = 'bar' ORDER BY `name` ASC LIMIT 250 OFFSET 0;
```

This query gives a filesort in explain, which is actually logical since the `product_count` is a range lookup. We use this count as '-1' equals 'unknown/not yet known', 0 means no products, >0 means `product_count` products. We want to filter out everything without products. To make this more efficient we planned on extra columns `has_products_XX` with triggers to update them automatically. This mitigates the range lookup. But having this inside `foo` doesn't seem very durable as the country-count grows with 3-4 a year. But having a `foo_countries` table makes the filtering happen on both sides which is very slow since there are currently 3M+ records in `foo` and there would be 3M+ x countries records in `foo_countries`.

Any ideas on how to handle these situations?

Comment: 1. What does `Product_Count` represent?  Number of `foo` offered in each country?  Inventory?  Context is important. 2. **Never** model 1 to many relationships flat.

Answer (score 0):

No.  As a generalization:  "Do not spread an array of things across columns".

Have another table, say `product_counts` that has a column for country (fr, de, etc).  It will have more rows than the current 'foo'.

If there are no products in a certain country, the row can be missing.  To get `0` instead of `NULL`, use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE(ct, 0)`.

`ALTER TABLE` (to add a column and index, etc) should be avoided.

If you want more discussion, please sketch out this redesign, but include some hints of what kind of data will be stored.  *And* provide a sample `SELECT`.

This design keeps:  '-1' equals 'unknown/not yet known', 0 means no products, but uses a missing row to mean 'unknown/not yet known' (instead of "-1").

Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to upsert counts into `product_counts`.